# How to create sub-class in my program (Shapes Area Calculator | JAVA)

Tags: java, class

I need help because I do have a problem on creating a sub-class in my program. I do only have a main-class as you can see below. I don't know how to create a sub-class for my formula to seperate it from my main class.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class shapes {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type 1 for the area of Circle \nType 2 for area of Triangle \nType 3 for Square \nType 4 for Rectangle \nType 5 for Octagon \nType 0 to exit.");

    int i = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

    if (i == 1) {
        String inpu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter radius of a circle: ");
        double radius = Integer.parseInt(inpu);
        b.areaCircle(radius);
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the base of a triangle: ");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String inp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height of a triangle: ");
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(inp);
        areaTriangle(n1, n2);
    }


    if (i == 3) {
        String sq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of a square: ");
        int sqno1 = Integer.parseInt(sq);
        String sq2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height of a square: ");
        int sqno2 = Integer.parseInt(sq2);
        areaSquare(sqno1, sqno2);
    }


    if (i == 4) {
        String inp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of a rectangle: ");
        int m1 = Integer.parseInt(inp);
        String inp2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of a rectangle: ");
        int m2 = Integer.parseInt(inp2);
        areaRectangle(m1, m2);
    }

    if (i == 5) {
        String oct = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the side of octagon: ");
        double octno = Double.parseDouble(oct);
        areaOctagon(octno);
    }

    else {
        return;
    }
}



public static void areaCircle(double radius) {
    double areac = Math.PI * (radius * radius); // MATH PI is equivalent of pi = 3.14159
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of a circle is: " + areac);
}

public static void areaTriangle(int n1, int n2) {
    int areat = (n1 * n2) / 2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of a triangle is: " + areat);
}

public static void areaSquare(int sqno1, int sqno2) {
    int asquare = (sqno1 * sqno2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of square is " + asquare);
}

public static void areaRectangle(int m1, int m2) {
    int arear = (m1 * m2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of a rectangle is: " + arear);

}

public static void areaOctagon(double octno) {
    double aoct = (2 * 2.414 * octno);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of a octagon is: " + aoct);

}


}
```

Can you help me to create a new sub-class for my program? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by sub-class? Please clarify your problem, explain it in plain English and then we will be able to help.

Comment: Like this one https://pastebin.com/wGf2y57X

The first one is for display
The second one which was the sub-class is for the formula

I just want to seperate the formula thing by creating a subclass. I hope you can help me with my problem thanks :)

Comment: Now I see what you want. You intend to create a class named Sub (which is not a subclass) and instantiate it as a static member of MainChick. To achieve this you need to create a Sub.java file inside the same package which includes Mainchick, or, if you do it in a different package, then you will need to either use its fully qualified name inside MainChick or import it. If you have difficulty working with packages, then you might want to tell us the IDE you use if any.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE (Oxygen)